# Regular expression - match the non digits at the end of a line

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the characters at the end of line that contains digits and spaces. For example

62 29N 23W 5 WATSON B

I'd like to match "WATSON B"

but also match "SMITH" in the case of

60 29N 22W 7 SMITH

Comment: Is it always a group of 1-2 digits, space, 1-2 digits and a letter, space, 1-2 digits and a letter, space, digit, space, and then the rest of what you would like? Or is there always a number and a space prior to what you would like?

Answer (score 1):

This simple regex should do it:

```
([A-Z]+ *)+$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/E8X6Z93tZt).

Comment: Will this get "WATSON B" or just "B"?

Comment: @KevinO "WATSON B"

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you are trying to do but you might want to try something like this:

```
\d{1,2} \d{1,2}[a-zA-Z] \d{1,2}[a-zA-Z] \d ([a-zA-Z\s]+)
```

`\d{1,2}` matches a character 1 to 2 times

`\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]` additionally requires a character

`([a-zA-Z\s]+)` captures the remaining characters if they are letters or a whitespace character

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it: `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$`

Made an edit. Initial regex caught space char before name.